# Upgrade NG13 -> NG14 Error: Providers from the `BrowserModule` have already been loaded

Tags: angular, module, loading, lazy-evaluation

I started this project 5 years ago with Angular 2+, till the NG 13 version everything is migrated well.
No I want to upgrade to NG 14, but now this error is popping up when I navigate to any of my lazy loaded modules!

Error: Providers from the `BrowserModule` have already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor, import the `CommonModule` instead. Error: Providers from the `BrowserModule` have already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor, import the `CommonModule` instead

So to be clear in my shared.module.ts I have only imported the CommonModule!
And in the app.module.ts there is only 1 Browser and BrowserAnimationsModule imported, also the shared module is imported within the imports: []!

I really don't have a clue what's going wrong here!

this is the app-routing.module.ts:

```
/* eslint-disable max-len */

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouteConfigLoadEnd, Router, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { addDynamicPath } from './softpak/classes/dynamic-path';
import { LandingPageComponent } from './softpak/components/landing-page/landing-page.component';
import { MainComponent } from './softpak/components/main/main.component';
import { NotfoundComponent } from './softpak/components/notfound/notfound.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './softpak/guards/auth.guard';
import { DynamicPathGuard } from './softpak/guards/dynamic-path.guard';
import { LicenseGuard } from './softpak/guards/license.guard';
import { SecurityGuard } from './softpak/guards/security.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: LandingPageComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },

      // Lazy loaded modules here!
      {
        path: 'accounting',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard, LicenseGuard],
        canActivateChild: [SecurityGuard],
        loadChildren: () => import('./applications/accounting/accounting.module').then(m => m.AccountingModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'general',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard, LicenseGuard],
        canActivateChild: [SecurityGuard],
        loadChildren: () => import('./applications/general/general.module').then(m => m.GeneralModule)
      },
      // etc.
    ]
  },
  { path: '404', component: NotfoundComponent },
  { path: '**', canActivate: [DynamicPathGuard], component: NotfoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules,
      paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always'
    })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.events.subscribe(routerEvent => {
      if (routerEvent instanceof RouteConfigLoadEnd) {
        addDynamicPath(this.router.config, routerEvent.route.path || '');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

this is the app.module.ts:

```
// imports here

// some of my components etc.
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MainComponent,
    ErrorComponent,
    LandingPageComponent,
    NavigationItemComponent,    
    NotfoundComponent,
    LogComponent,
    AttachmentsComponent,
    UpdateNotificationComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    IntlModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', {
      enabled: environment.production
    }),
    ThemeModule.forRoot({
      themes: [defaultTheme, lightTheme, darkTheme, customTheme],
      active: 'default'
    }),
    SharedModule
  ],
  providers: [
    // my services comes here
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This is the shared.module.ts

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
// all my shared components here, some Kendo Components and other third party stuff


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    // my shared components here
  ],
  providers: [],
  exports: [
    RouterModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    // my shared components here
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

This is the Accounting.module.ts

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared.module';
import { AccountingRoutingModule } from './accounting-routing.module';
import { AccountingComponent } from './accounting.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, SharedModule, AccountingRoutingModule],
  declarations: [AccountingComponent]
})
export class AccountingModule {}
```

And this is the general.module.ts:

```
// imports here
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, SharedModule, GeneralRoutingModule],
  declarations: [
    GeneralComponent,
    // the rest of my custom components here
  ]
})
export class GeneralModule {}
```

Comment: Please share the module of accounting and general lazy loading

Comment: Hi @NarenMurali, thanks for watching this issue! I've updated my question with the 2 missing module files, thanks!

Comment: has anyone run into this yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use 'angular2-notifications' package.

I had imported SimpleNotificationsModule in AppModule and SharedModule. I used `<simple-notifications [options]="options"></simple-notifications>` in child component.

After update Angular version from 12 to 13 i had 'BrowserModule has already been loaded' error.

I removed SimpleNotificationsModule from SharedModule and error is gone. I had to move `<simple-notifications [options]="options"></simple-notifications>` to AppComponent

```
import { SimpleNotificationsModule } from 'angular2-notifications';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,
    SimpleNotificationsModule // removed this line
  ],
  exports: [
    ...,
    SimpleNotificationsModule // removed this line
  ],
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

```
import { SimpleNotificationsModule } from 'angular2-notifications';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        SimpleNotificationsModule.forRoot() // left this line
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! This one did it for me!!

For some reason I didn't have the module imported, but only the notificationService directly injected into my own service, and this did work (for some reason without importing the module) till NG 13!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @PatrickRitskes, I am glad to hear it! If error is gone, please mark the answer as accepted